# React Cannot POST to /api/users/login

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express

I have encountered an error Cannot POST to /api/users/login in the production mode. It works correctly on the localhost but results in 404 in deployment and on Postman. All other requests work correctly both on localhost and in production.

server.js

```
const usersRoutes = require("./routes/usersRoutes");
app.use("/api/users", usersRoutes);
```

usersRoutes.js

```
router.post("/login", loginUser);
```

usersControllers.js

```
const loginUser = async (req, res) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body;
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ username, password });
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(404).json({ error: "No such record exists." });
    } else {
      return res.status(200).json(user);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return res.status(500).json({ error: "Internal Server Error" });
  }
};
```

loginPage.js

```
const handleSubmitLoginForm = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const response = await fetch("/api/users/login", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify({ username, password }),
    });
    const json = await response.json();

    if (!response.ok) {
      console.log(json.error);
    } else {
      setUsername("");
      setPassword("");
      authorizeDispatch({ type: "SET_AUTH", payload: true });
      console.log(json);
    }
  };
```

nginx configurations on Hostinger:

```
server {
    server_name school-dashboard.chernysn.tech www.school-dashboard.chernysn.tech;


    location /static {
        # Serve the frontend from the build directory
        root /home/natasha/MERN/frontend/build;
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }


    location / {
        proxy_pass http://82.197.92.74:5000;   
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }



    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/school-dashboard.chernysn.tech/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/school-dashboard.chernysn.tech/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}


server {
    if ($host = school-dashboard.chernysn.tech) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name school-dashboard.chernysn.tech;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

I searched online for a possible solution but nothing really worked and I cannot figure out why. Thank you!